# Node.js path.join() ignoring parameter

Tags: node.js

According to the documentation:

> The path.join() method joins all given path segments together using
>   the platform-specific separator as a delimiter, then normalizes the
>   resulting path.
>
> Zero-length path segments are ignored. If the joined path string is a
>   zero-length string then '.' will be returned, representing the current
>   working directory.
>
> ```
> path.join('/foo', 'bar', 'baz/asdf', 'quux', '..');
> // Returns: '/foo/bar/baz/asdf'
>
> path.join('foo', {}, 'bar');
> // Throws 'TypeError: Path must be a string. Received {}'
> ```
>
> A TypeError is thrown if any of the path segments is not a string.

Am  I missing something? Why is:

```
 path.join('/foo', 'bar', 'baz/asdf', 'quux', '..');
    // Returns: '/foo/bar/baz/asdf'
```

Ignoring `'quux'` and `'..'` ?

They're are not zero length?

Even played around in the REPL (see screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Agree with Golo’s answer, object doesn’t make sense here. Re: ignoring - It’s the same as doing “$ cd quux && cd ..”

Comment: `path.join` calls this validation function on your parameters: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/path.js#L750

Answer (score 6):

Path.join isn't ignoring the last two parameters. Path.join takes the parameters you input and outputs a normalized path in string format.

So what's actually going on here is that it's constructing your string to form a path left to right, `/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux/`, and the last parameter (..) is instructing path.join to 'go back a directory'. So your final result will be: `/foo/bar/baz/asdf/`

Answer (score 0):

Part 1: what do you expect to happen when you provide an object instead of a string? To cut it short: It doesn’t make sense and hence doesn’t work.

Part 2: since .. means „up one directory“, this clears the last part of the path, hence it seems to not have any effect. Actually, it doesn’t get ignored - it’s just that the last two parameters clear each other.

Comment: I don't think he intended to provide an object, that whole part is an example from the https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths documentation. The second part of your answer should answer this question imo.

Answer (score -1):

1. With regard to `path.join('foo', {}, 'bar');`, `{}` represents an empty object, not a string (empty or not). Therefore, it is an invalid parameter for `path.join()`.
2. With regard to `path.join('/foo', 'bar', 'baz/asdf', 'quux', '..');`, `..` refers to a parent directory.
   Through experimentation in a terminal, you will find that...

   `/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux/..` is equivalent to `/foo/bar/baz/asdf`